# Objective-C property name mapping

Tags: objective-c, properties

I wonder if there is an easy and fast way to map a property name from adopted protocol to the property which already comes from a base class?

Suppose the example:

```
@protocol Proto <NSObject>
    @property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString *objectId;
@end
...
@interface MyBase : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString *objectId;
@end
...
@interface MyClass : MyBase<Proto>
@end
```

In this case I guess I don't need to do anything - the property is just there together with the getter and the setter so the promise to have them given when adopting the protocol is fulfilled. But what if the property in `MyBase` is called `objId` and **not** `objectId`? Are there any language tricks using `dynamic`, `synthesize`, `getter=` or any other way to make it refer to the base class' property without manually defining a getter/setter in `MyClass` and returning/setting base class' property?

**Rationale:** I want to cover a third party library by a protocol layer which will be used by UI so that I can easily change the provider to another similar one under the hood (or provide a simulator for testing). The protocols I define mostly replicate the API of this library, however some property names include their naming which I don't want to be in my interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C does offer hooks such as `-(id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector` which works much like Ruby's `method_missing`. You can use this to redirect Objective-C messages to other objects and/or selectors. So if you have a consistent but different naming pattern in the properties e.g. *objectId -> objId, you could use that. CAVEAT Using any of this stuff is risky - if you can accomplish the same thing with a few overrides, do that instead. Your code will be much less fragile, even if it isn't quite so clean